# Any idea why the $\tt hat$ "$\hat{}$" is a bit off?

Tags: discussion, bug

I am noticing that the hat accent in $\textrm{"\hat"}$ is a bit off for the past days, going top-right as an exponent. And that's for both inline and display mode. Even the entry on the [famous MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) got the "hats" off. And the $\textrm{"\vec"}$ as I see.

Maybe more accents to discover. I have seen this on other SE sites as well. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

- From @Peter K.'s answer down, it looks like it's only from my computer as shown on the image below:

  [image]
- From @Fat32 's comment (see attached image below), I am still seeing the same thing. I don't know what's wrong.

  [image]

**EDIT2:**
And that's the same comment rendered on my (fat32) computer:
[image]

Comment: hmmm this is a hat $\hat{a}$ ? And I see it ok...

Comment: Thanks @Fat32 , I don't know what's wrong on my computer but I still see the hat shifted a bit to the right. Let me upload a screenshot.

Comment: @Fat32  , I have no clue what's going on. At first I thought I wasn't the only one, so far it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Fat32 , please see my answer, now I know I am not alone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure? It looks OK to me: $\hat a$ ?

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter ! From here your line's still off, got the $a$ with the hat top- right, but the image looks good. I have attached a screenshot in the edited answer. I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

So I found that this has to do with the recent Safari update to version 10.1. My issue and screenshots are from Safari 10.1.1.

This is also reported on [Physics meta SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/mathjax-shifted-frames?rq=1), on [mathoverflow meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3207/mathjax-accents-in-safari-10-1), and explained in [issue #1709 on the MathJax tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1709).

**UPDATE:**

As of today (September 25th, 2017) with Safari 11.0, this issue has been fixed. All exponent symbols fall right in place. Cheers !

Comment: That's interesting !

Comment: Could be a MathJax update, now also `cases` behaves more like it does in LaTeX, formatting the second column as text.